# Can one obtain a visa for a third country in their home country if they do not currently live in the home country?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, russian-citizens

Suppose a Russian citizen who studies (hence lives) in the US [on an F-1 visa] wants to get a Schengen visa to visit the Netherlands. If they happen to be in Russia during a break, can they apply for such a visa through the Netherlands Visa Application Centre in Moscow, or will their application be denied (asking them to apply for a visa in the US where they currently reside) since they do not currently live in Russia? Further, whatever the answer to this question is, does it generalize to visas of all other countries, or is it specific to the Netherlands (or Schengen visas)?

Comment: not an answer, but a hint: on F1 visa you are not "residing" in the US (only green card will allow that), i don't know if shengen distinguishes between "live" and "be resident"

Comment: Not an answer but often the requirement is ‘legally present’. I doubt there’s any rule to prevent you from applying for a visa from your country of citizenship, regardless of where you’re currently living.

Comment: I think some countries do require application from your area of residence. I'm a British citizen, but the Chinese consulate in Los Angeles was definitely the right place for me to file a visa application, because I live in Southern California.

Comment: @aaaaaa Where one is resident differs for different purposes. I was tax resident in the US for several years before I became a "Lawful Permanent Resident" (green card).

Comment: @aaaaaa For visa purposes, students are considered residents in the US while they live there.

Comment: Some countries will only accept applications to the consulate that serves your area of residence. Others recommend doing so. Others still don't care. Note that it's always better to do so, especially if there is anything special about the requester's situation, as the consular officers serving that area are more familiar with the specifics of that area (e.g. local customs in terms of bank accounts, pay slips, and other arrangements).

Answer (score 1):

**You can request Schengen visa from other countries than your residence.**

That might require explaining why it is a *special hardship* for you to follow the usual process, and starting a visa appication by explaining why *you* are a special case is not the best way to go about it. Officials like orderly, standard procedures.

Check if it is still possible for you to follow the usual procedure. If so, do it.

**You cannot generalize.**

Most countries reserve the right to issue visas to anyone, anywhere, if they feel like it. But getting into that special process may be difficult.